# Format the LaTeX code of an array

Tags: formatting, tools

Is there any editor that can nicely format the LaTeX code for an array? By nicely format I mostly have in mind aligning the `&`, as in the examples below:

---

Example 1:

```
\begin{array}{lcl}
z & = & a \\
& = & a \\
f(x,y,z) & = & x + y + z
\end{array}
```

could be formatted to:

```
\begin{array}{lcl}
z        & = & a         \\
         & = & a         \\
f(x,y,z) & = & x + y + z
\end{array}
```

---

Example 2:

```
\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 
  {1}&{ 2}  &{ \mathbf M}  \\
  {48941} & {-3} &  { \mathbf M}  \\
  {11} & { 6}  & {-\mathbf M} 
\end{bmatrix*}
```

could be formatted to:

```
\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 
  {1} & { 2}  & { \mathbf M}  \\
  {1} & {-3}  & { \mathbf M}  \\
  {1} & { 6}  & {-\mathbf M} 
\end{bmatrix*}
```

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: @Mico Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: And which editor? Are you aware of `latexindent` by cmhughes? It is designed specifically for such purposes.

Comment: @HarishKumar I use Texmaker but don't mind using another editor for formatting. I wasn't aware of latexindent, I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: It is there in texlive. For miktex, you may need this: https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl

Comment: not relevant to the question, but example 1 would be better handled by `align` rather than an `array`.

Comment: Texstudio has an option to `Align Columns` in the toolbar. I never used it though.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, I have just tried, it works great!

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you add an answer here?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Hi Johannes, I have converted my comments in to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Independent of the editor being used, we have [latexindent](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en) by Chris (cmhughes). This should do a good job in beautifying the latex code by indenting everything.

On the other hand there is a `Align Columns` option in texstudio (which a cousin of texmaker) where you select

```
1 &  2  &  \mathbf M  \\
1 & -3  &  \mathbf M  \\
1 &  6  & -\mathbf M
```

and then click the tab to align them.

[image]

Aside there is no need to enclose the entries within braces since the entries are already inside a group here.

Comment: Congrats on making the 199K club! :-)

Comment: @HarishKumar - You're most welcome! Of course, by now you're well past the 200K mark... :-)